# Can we reset page or object in r shiny without reloading page

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shinyapps

**Problem1**: I created a shiny application in which when user commit any record to database entire page gets reloaded which i don't want i just want to reset/refresh my object in R shiny without entire page reload.Is there any alternative to achieve the same?

**Problem2**:Also in my application i have one login page so i want when user enters their credentials it should store the credentials in that field so that when user again login to the same page it should not ask to enter credentials along with password not by using browser functionality to remember password.Also when they close the browser and again open new instance of browser it should ask for credentials.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

it is always good if you have any reproducible example for your problem statement.
For your problem 1 there is a package shinyjs. You can use it for reset your object. The sample code for problem 1:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
        h2("shinyjs demo"),
        textInput("name", "Name", ""),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
        actionButton("reset", "Reset form")

  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      shinyjs::alert( paste("Thank you!",input$name) )
    })

    observeEvent(input$reset, {
      shinyjs::reset("name")
    })    
  }
)
```

You can have the documentation here. https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs

For your problem 2 there are few relative things. It can handled by browser also.
You can use this documentation link https://gist.github.com/calligross/e779281b500eb93ee9e42e4d72448189

Comment: For **problem1** you are trying to reset with blank space which is still a character and i want the object to get refresh as nothing stored in it.

For **Problem2** you suggested me with cookie functionality.I just want it simple that when i open my application and enter my credentials the text value should store the credentials just like browser remember password functionality.So that next time i don't suppose to enter again it should be populated in field.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example for you r problem 1? and problem 2 I cant remember any solution which can do this thing except js and browser combination...